# How to extract performance values from aggregate graph table of jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter for performance testing. I want to get performance values from aggregate graph table of jmeter in csv/xml file format.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save the results in csv format using `Aggregate Report` listener using "Save Table Data" option.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report

both Aggregate Graph and Aggregate Report shows the same tabular data. so, you can load the results file (.csv/.jtl) to `Aggregate Report` listener (using `Browse` option). then click on "Save Table Data" button and save the file in `csv` format..

Comment: in case if I have to run this .jmx script from command line, is there a way I can do this?

Comment: I don't know. I guess As long as the Aggregate Report listener is added to JMX script, it doesn't matter whether we run it from Command line or UI. I would suggest trying with sample JMX file to confirm the listener is generating the expected results.